# Function to remove only some rows among huge table of data in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, filtering

I need your help with this issue I have in Excel 2016 (english).

I havea lot of data, structured like this:

```
code_red    value_1
code_green  value_2
code_green  value_3
code_green  value_4
code_green  value_5
code_blue   value_6
```

I need to use a function that allows me to get:

```
code_red    value_1
code_green  value_2
code_green  value_5
code_blue   value_6
```

I tried with `Remove duplicate` but I need to keep the last row among the duplicates.

**Moreover**, I need that the same principle applies also later down in my data, so let's say that if I have:

```
code_black  value_101
code_green  value_102
code_green  value_103
code_green  value_104
code_yellow value_105
```

I need to be able to obtain:

```
code_black  value_101
code_green  value_102
code_green  value_104
code_yellow value_105
```

Keep in mind that I have a table with more than 2000 lines, so I cannot do it manually everytime, that's why I need a function/macro to do that. Hopefully you can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveIntermediateRows()

    Dim R As Range, Rstart As Range

    Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'set initial range
    Set Rstart = R ' set the start of the value range (equal to the initial range at first)

    Do Until R = "" 'loop termination condition; we are assuming contiguous rows of data here, and it ends at a blank value

        ' if we have a new value
        If R.Value <> Rstart.Value Then ' (this will always be false on the first row of course)
        ' then R(0) is the end of the previous value range,
        ' and Rstart is the start of the previous value range

            ' if there is at least 1 row between R(0) and Rstart
            ' then build a range of those intermediate rows (one row before R(0), one row after Rstart)
            ' and delete them
            If R(0).row - Rstart.row > 1 Then Range(R(-1), Rstart(2)).EntireRow.Delete

            Set Rstart = R ' set the start of the new value range
        End If

        Set R = R(2) 'move to next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Note: If you have a lot of data, I recommend changing `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` and `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` at the start of the Sub, and then changing it back at the end of the Sub, as this will make performance better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula below in `D2`. Drag the formula down, filter on `FALSE` values and delete.

```
=OR(A2<>A1,A2<>A3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. However, your solution requires too many steps/clicks, that's why my favorite solution is the one proposed by @Tigregalis

Comment: No problem, but for what it's worth. I'd recommend you avoid using VBA unless it's actually necessary.